# Symfony2 - Pulling data from database and show in forms

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I want to show the data on my forms but I am not able to do so.

**Here is my profile.php under userbundle:**

```
 <?php

namespace project\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Profile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project_profiles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \project\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\project\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address1", type="string")
     */
    private $address1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address2", type="string")
     */
    private $address2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string")
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string")
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string")
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="client_api_delay", type="integer")
     */
    private $clientApiDelay;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set address1
     *
     * @param string $address1
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setAddress1($address1)
    {
        $this->address1 = $address1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress1()
    {
        return $this->address1;
    }

    /**
     * Set address2
     *
     * @param string $address2
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setAddress2($address2)
    {
        $this->address2 = $address2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress2()
    {
        return $this->address2;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set zipcode
     *
     * @param string $zipcode
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setZipcode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zipcode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getZipcode()
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param string $country
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set clientApiDelay
     *
     * @param integer $clientApiDelay
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setClientApiDelay($clientApiDelay)
    {
        $this->clientApiDelay = $clientApiDelay;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get clientApiDelay
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getClientApiDelay()
    {
        return $this->clientApiDelay;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt to NOW
     *
     * @return Profile
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtNow()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt to NOW
     *
     * @return Profile
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedAtNow()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \project\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Profile
     */
    public function setUser(\project\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \project\UserBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**My ProfileController.php file:**

```
<?php

namespace project\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use project\UserBundle\Entity\Profile;
use project\UserBundle\Form\ProfileType;

/**
 * Profile controller.
 *
 * @Route("/admin/profile")
 */
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Profile entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="admin_profile")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="admin_profile_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("projectUserBundle:Profile:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity  = new Profile();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $entity);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_profile_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="admin_profile_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Profile();
        $form   = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_profile_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Profile entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_profile_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Profile entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_profile_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("projectUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Profile entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new ProfileType(), $entity);
        $editForm->bind($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_profile_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a Profile entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="admin_profile_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Profile entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_profile'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Profile entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

I have declared my entities under Resources/Profile/show.html and everything works:
For example for address I have:

```
<th>Address2</th>
<td>{{ entity.address2 }}</td>
```

My problem is I have another bundle called ShowBundle and I want to show those entities on that bunddle. For e.g When I call {{ entity.address2 }} on that bundle to show my address it shows me that: *(variable "entity" doesnt exist)*

How I can display those profile entities on the twig forms in another bundle, in my case ShowBundle?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For the user, I am ale to show by using {{ app.user.variablename }} even though I use in another bundle. How I can do that to show the entities I have listed above that are under my profile?

Comment: I'd suggest following the code that's in your `ProfileController` under the `showAction`. This should work.

Comment: Thanks antony. I tried following your suggestion but I have another error now.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can use `{{ app.user.variablename }}` which is a global. But for other variable, a view can only display the data the controller send to it. That's the MVC (Model-View-Controller) architecture.

Variable `entity` exist in the Twig view only if your controller send it to the view. That's what the lines `return array( 'entities' => $entities );` do on your ProfileController.php, and that's why you can use it in Resources/Profile/show.html.

If you want to display an entity in another bundle, just pull it from the database and send it to the view the same way you do in your ProfileController.php. If you wrote yourself the code you posted, that should be an easy task.

If you do not understand the code you posted, I suggest you learn to use Symfony. You can read [the Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html), which is excellent step-by-step documentation.

**Tips :**

copy-past this code in your other bundle controllers (the methods ending with `Action()`) :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); //get the database manager

$profiles = $em->getRepository('projectUserBundle:Profile')->findAll(); // get the profiles

return array(
        'profiles' => $profiles,
    ); // send data to the view
```

You will access your profiles through `{{ profiles }}` in your templates.

Comment: Thank you. I have another error now: Key "address1" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in /var/www/project-symfony/projectSymfony/src/project/FrontendBundle/Resources/views/Frontend/myproject.html.twig at line 158

Comment: You should learn to use Symfony an learn PHP for real.
You use the method `findAll();` that means you get an array of profiles, not one profile. (That's why I wrote it in plural =P) So you have to `foreach` on profileS to get profile one by one, or to specify which profile of the array you want : `profiles[0].address1` to get address of first profile and `profile[1].address1` to get address of second profile.

Comment: You have to learn. Read Symfony's book. Try to understand the general concept of `array` which exist if almost all programming language, and you will understand your error messages, which are quite clear for someone who knows how to program.